# DataSet's column name coincides with Item property

Tags: powershell

I'm interacting with Oracle via PowerShell:

```
$Query = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, INI, ITEM FROM ...'

$command = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($Query, $connection)

$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
(New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter($command)).Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

$dataSet.Tables[0]
```

Unfortunately, the `ITEM` column coincides with the `System.Data.DataRow`'s `Item` property.  As a result, the `ITEM` column isn't listed by the `Format-Table` or `Format-List` cmdlets.

The data is accessible by calling the property directly, however:

```
PS> $dataSet[0].ITEM
12345
```

Other than creating a column alias in the query (`ITEM as ITM`, perhaps), is there a way to get the `ITEM` property to be displayed when using `Format-Table` or `Format-List`?

** edit **

This syntax works, however:

```
PS> $dataSet[0] | select ini, item

INI  ITEM
---  ----
XXX  12345
```

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

take row 0 column 0

```
$dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
```

or like this

```
$dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"]
```

if you search column name

```
$dataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName
```